# Android sdk error not found at the specificlocation

Tags: android, xamarin-studio

I installed the xamarin studio and other components and after installing the sdk for it says  that the  android sdk not found  at specific location.
I tried both zip and exe from the following url but in vain.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
thanks
adnan shahid..

Answer (score 0):

Install android studio and then point the sdk towards the sdk that comes with android studio solved the problem in some cases when there is problem with downloading android sdk from the site or missing some files.